# Knex SQL Query Returning Nothing, MySQL Workbench Returns Proper Data

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

Trying to simply get a list of discordid's from my twitch_webhook table. This query comes out as `SELECT * FROM twitch_webhook`. In MySQL Workbench this query gives me the data I want, but in Knex/nodejs when I make the exact same query it returns `[]`. Querying other tables in the same DB works as intended: its just this one. 
I have confirmed that the query that knex sends to my db is the exact same (except twitch_webhook is in 's).
Any idea on what could be causing this would be great, or perhaps other ways of troubleshooting.

```
let twitch = await connection('twitch_webhook').select('*').catch(console.error).then(console.log);
```

Comment: your original table name might have had case sensitive name, and when you didn't use quotes around table name, it might have done case insensitive query... I'm pretty sure it actually didn't have anything to do with the underscore (it is commonly used with knex and mysql).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the underscore in the table name: `twitch_webhook`. Something about character encoding. Removing the underscore from the name fixed the issue.